# is it possible for a UDP socket to receive an ARP message

Tags: linux, sockets, udp, arp

I have created a udp socket under linux to discover another system on the network.
After creating a udp socket and assigning src IP , src Port, dst port (I know the correct value) and a dst IP (broadcast), application sends a UDP packet to the other end. The idea is to make the other computer sends back a UDP packet so my computer deduce the destination IP address. The other end is responding with an ARP message that contains its IP, port as well as my IP&port.

Although, the socket I am using is datagram my application declares the other end is discovered and can get its IP. It seems like the udp socket I am using has received the ARP message sent by the other end, which looks confusing to me.

Please has anyone an explanation of what happens.

Thank you very much.

Comment: How do you know that the other end is responding with an ARP? Why do you think it is ARP?

Comment: Hi Rodrigo, I included more details below.

Answer (score 7):

ARP is not a UDP based protocol and thus cannot be captured with an UDP socket. Have a look at the [OSI layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model) and you will find ARP at layer 2..3 (link..network) while UDP is at the transport layer (layer 4). Without ARP UDP cannot even work in the local network.

If you send an UDP packet from your socket it will look into the ARP cache of the system to find out the hardware address (MAC) associated with the target IP address (at least if the target IP is inside the same local network). If there is no valid cached entry it will do an ARP request. This ARP request is "owned" by the kernel an it is not associated with your socket, even if the send on your socket caused the ARP lookup. Once the kernel (not your socket) receives the ARP reply it will know the targets MAC address and can thus encapsulate your IP packet (UDP is based on IP) into a frame for the local (physical) network (with the local and target MAC included) and send it out through the network card.

Comment: Actually, this is why I am confused. I know that it does not make sense that a raw Ethernet message such as ARP is captured by a high level interface like udp socket. However, I cannot find other explanation of how my computer is getting to recognize the IP address of the other end in my application.

Comment: @user2410592 Why do you think that your UDP socket captures an ARP frame ?

Comment: @user2410592: I added more details and I hope it should be clearer now how the UDP socket and the ARP packets relate to each other.

Comment: Thank you Steffen. Actually, I know the ARP process and how it works. I will try to more elaborate my description:

Comment: actually, I am connecting two ends to a switch and using another computer (also connected to the switch) running wireshark I am able to see the traffic between both computers. The process is as follows:

Comment: After powering both computers, the other end starts sending 2 broadcast ARP messages (one of them is Gratuitous). Then, my computer sends a broadcast udp packet to the other end (without sending an ARP first to know its MAC address, as I said udp packet uses broadcast addresses for both IP and MAC). After a short time, the other end responds with an Request ARP message that holds its IP and MAC as well as my IP. Then, my computer does not respond to that ARP request. Nevertheless, my application (with udp socket) gets to recognize the other end IP address then resume execution.

Comment: "The other end is responding with an ARP message that contains its IP, port as well as my IP&port." - I don't know what you are seeing, but ARP packets do not contain port numbers. ARP connect layer 2 (MAC) with 3 (IP) but port is layer 4. Maybe you should illustrate your question with a tcpdump so that others see what really is going on and how your question relates to that.

Comment: Beware! Switches usually filter the IP traffic based on the MAC addresses they see on each port. Chances are that you are only seeing broadcast messages and missing the normal ones. You should try running a packet sniffer in one of the target machines.

Comment: @user2410592 You need to tell us what  "my application (with udp socket) gets to recognize the other end IP address then resume execution" means. What does your code **actually do** ? Perhaps it receives an UDP packet, I'll ask again, why do you think your application receive an ARP packet and not an UDP packet ? Perhaps it does receive an UDP packet. Perhaps it receives an ICMP packet that are translated to an error. Perhaps your send or receive calls fail, and therefore resumes execution, but you didn't check for failure. Perhaps your code does something else.